# asp.net treeview and xpath

Tags: asp.net, xpath, treeview

Im trying to bind a asp.net treeview with an xmldatasource that uses the web.sitemap file. However I only want to show certain nodes from the web.sitemap.

In the web.sitemap file I have set an attribute ShowInSiteEditor="True" if I want to view it in the tree view.

I have set the XPath of the xmldatasource to //*[@ShowInSiteEditor='True']

If I use a repeater control It only shows the nodes that have the ShowInEditor="True", however if I use a treeview control it shows all the nodes and ignores the XPAth selection.

Below is the code that Im using:

```
<asp:XmlDataSource ID="XmlDataSource1" runat="server" DataFile="~/Web.sitemap" XPath="//*[@ShowInSiteEditor='True']" >
    </asp:XmlDataSource> 

    <asp:TreeView ID="Selector" runat="server" DataSourceID="XmlDataSource1"  >
        <DataBindings>
            <asp:TreeNodeBinding DataMember="siteMapNode" TextField="title" />
        </DataBindings>
    </asp:TreeView>
```

Does Anyone have any advice??
James

Comment: I have realised what has happened here. The code is showing the nodes of the web.sitemap that has ShowInEdior="True", however it is also showing all the child nodes that regardless of wether or not they have ShowInEditor set to true or false!